# Nested Where In in Doctrine2

Tags: php, mysql, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I want to create this statement in Doctrine 2 :

```
SELECT Id, ParentId , LastName
  FROM Customer
 WHERE ParentId IN 
       (SELECT Id 
          FROM Customer
          WHERE ParentId IN $id)
       )
```

Here is my code :

```
    public function findByCustomer($id) : array
    {
    $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb1 = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb->select('Customer.Id , Customer.ParentId ,  Customer.LastName ');
    $qb->from('..\City\Model\Entities\Customer', 'Customer');       
    $qb->add('where', $qb->expr()->in('Customer.ParentId',

            $qb1->select('Customer.Id');
            $qb1->from('..\City\Model\Entities\Customer', 'Customer');      
            $qb1->add('where', $qb->expr()->in('Customer.ParentId', $id)
            $qb1 = $qb1->getQuery();
            return $qb1->getResult();               

        )
    );
    $qb = $qb->getQuery();
    return $qb->getResult();
}
```

But it doesn't work at all . Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

You can bild a subquery via querybuilder like this:

```
$subQuery = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
$subQuery->select('c1.Id');
$subQuery->from('..\City\Model\Entities\Customer', 'c1');      
$subQuery->add('where', $qb->expr()->in('c1.ParentId', $id)


$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();

$qb->select('Customer.Id , Customer.ParentId ,  Customer.LastName ');
$qb->from('..\City\Model\Entities\Customer', 'Customer');       

$qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('Customer.ParentId',  $subQuery->getDQL()) );


$query = $qb->getQuery();
return $query->getResult();
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

I have antoher way to execute this query i hope this will help you. 
You can use direct sql statement in `doctrine2` like this

```
$sql = "SELECT Id, ParentId , LastName
  FROM Customer
 WHERE ParentId IN 
       (SELECT Id 
          FROM Customer
          WHERE ParentId IN $id)
       )";
 $data = $this->doctrine->sql_conn->fetchAll($sql , array());
```

I always use this one to write complicated sql statement in `doctrine2`. I hope this will help you